LLDB convenience function in Python
Is it possible to write an LLDB extension in Python which provides a function which can be used in expressions at the LLDB command-line, similar to this for GDB?
I've searched the LLDB Python API documentation and found how to add commands, type formatters, and synthetic child providers. I'm in the process of creating scripts using these facilities (with underlying code portable between LLDB and GDB). We have a convenience function which we use in GDB, and are considering writing more, but if that's not possible in LLDB we might use some sort of command instead.

A lot of the functionality in these pseudo-functions - like finding elements in the containing stack - aren't really germane to expression evaluation.  They are in gdb's print because in gdb that's much more of a general purpose "tell me stuff about the debugee" command.  In lldb, some of the reporting provided by these functions would in lldb be more appropriate as separate commands.
lldb's print is an attempt to say "what would happen if this code were run right here in this debugee".  lldb's expression evaluator tries to be as close to a language accurate embedded compiler as is workable, acting "as if the code was run in the current frame".  So it is very selective about introducing non-language features.
Note, if you need some special test or access methods in your lldb expression s, you can introduce your own functions to the expression evaluator.  The command:
(lldb) expr bool $_isvoid(void *ptr) { return ptr == nullptr; }
will make a function called $_isvoid that you can call in other expressions.  This won't however, have the feature of the gdb ones, that it can be called regardless of whether the target is running or not.  It will make a real function in the debuggee's memory and actually call it.

Thank you. Unfortunately LLDB's expression evaluator doesn't know how to evaluate OCaml expressions (and this is unlikely to change any time soon). Also the OCaml type system is not (currently) recorded in DWARF, so is not available to LLDB. In Python it is fairly straightforward to do some things relating to OCaml's tag-discriminated immediate/pointer uniform value representation, with the limited runtime type information present in value tags and block headers. So I will switch to plan B and write some commands, rather than expressions, in Python for both LLDB and GDB.

FWIW I think this must be a fairly common problem for languages with their own compilers with native back-ends.

lldb's type system doesn't require the use of DWARF or a clang based frontend.  The type system interface in lldb is more general than that.  For instance, the swift type system gets its type information from runtime metadata as well as the compiler's native swift modules, and not from DWARF.  The ObjC type system is heavily augmented by runtime metadata as well.
That requires adding language support to lldb proper, however.  That is not a trivial amount of work, but would be consistent with lldb's overall design.

Similarly, the expression evaluation back end has a general architecture for back ends, though at present the llvm back-end is the only one actually supported.  However, if your back-end is significantly different, it could also be plugged in.  Of course "general architectures with one implementation" are usually not as general as their authors would hope...  But that's more a practical than a theoretical difficulty.

These are all very helpful comments, thank you.
